# Erasing everything from every element in a list except the first few numbers in those elements

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list in Python that looks like this:

```
['29382 this is something', '2938535 hello there', '392835 dont care for this', '22024811 yup']
```

I need to process it so that it like this:

```
['29382', '2938535', '392835', '22024811']
```

How would I go on about doing this?
I guess I could use re, but I don't know how to apply it in this situation.

Comment: StackOverflow is around to help you with your implementation. Please, show us what you attempted to do, or ideas you had, especially if you can include some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `regex` for this, you can use `split` within a list comprehension.

```
>>> l = ['29382 this is something', '2938535 hello there', '392835 dont care for this', '22024811 yup']

>>> [i.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in l]
['29382', '2938535', '392835', '22024811']
```

Comment: Thank you for that! It does the job, but I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: @Michel What confuses you, the `split` function or the list comprehension?

Comment: @Cyber The list comprehension

Comment: @Michel A list comprehension is essentially just a concise way to replace a `for` loop. [See here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). They are very powerful, clean, and pythonic so they are definitely worth learning.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
>>> l=['29382 this is something', '2938535 hello there', '392835 dont care for this', '22024811 yup']
>>> import re
>>> [ re.sub(r'\D', '', x) for x in l]
['29382', '2938535', '392835', '22024811']
```